# What is the INPUT_direct chain in firewalld?

Tags: linux, iptables, configuration, firewalld

In many firewalld config examples I see mention of the normal `INPUT` iptables chain, as well as one named `INPUT_direct`.

e.g.

```bash
$ sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 0 \
  # etc...

$ sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 1 \
  # etc...
```

What is the significance of `INPUT_direct`? Must I use it instead of `INPUT`?

And what is the difference between `INPUT_direct 0`, `INPUT_direct 1`, etc.?

Comment: Maybe, tread from developers of firewalld helps https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/firewalld-users@lists.fedorahosted.org/thread/5PBK6WUBFC2VA4F76YG33YX6UXZYMIYY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

- if direct rules are really needed, just always use `INPUT` rather than `INPUT_direct`: it will always work.
- if you don't know what priority value to use, just increase the priority value by one for each new direct rule to add.

---

This chain is (sometimes) used by the [direct rules](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.direct.html) interface of *firewalld*. This interface/feature allows to store custom *iptables* rules (and always *iptables* even when *firewalld*'s backend is *nftables*) using *firewalld* and ensure that these rules are the first seen by any packet (here in the `filter` table and `INPUT` chain). Normally you should use it only if something can't be handled by *firewalld* including by *firewalld*'s [rich language](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.richlanguage.html).

And this is a [deprecated feature](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.direct.html#deprecated):

> ### deprecated
>
> The direct interface has been deprecated. It will be removed in a
> future release. It is superseded by policies, see
> [firewalld.policies(5)](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.policies.html).

I'm not really sure it's superseded by policies for all of its uses, anyway...

Just as deprecated is the *iptables* backend. A typical installation on a recent system also includes in `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf`:

> ```
> # FirewallBackend
> # Selects the firewall backend implementation.
> # Choices are:
> # - nftables (default)
> # - iptables (iptables, ip6tables, ebtables and ipset)
> # Note: The iptables backend is deprecated. It will be removed in a future
> # release.
> FirewallBackend=nftables
> ```

*firewalld* can use either *iptables* or *nftables* as backend, but the direct rules are always using *iptables*. There is no concept of *nftables* direct rule even when the backend is *nftables*: that's probably one of the reasons that made direct rules deprecated.

- when the backend is *iptables*

  - *firewalld* creates the `INPUT_direct` chain and adds as first rule in `INPUT` a jump to `INPUT_direct` so it's always the first chain to see packets (in the `INPUT` path).
  - any reference to `INPUT` in a direct rule is switched to a reference to `INPUT_direct`
- when the backend is *nftables*

  - *firewalld* doesn't create by itself any *iptables* chain or rule, but ensures its own *nftables* rules are hooked to Netfilter at the priority *iptables* would have used +10.

  So for `INPUT` it hooks at priority 10 instead of 0. This ensures again that anything *iptables* does will do it first

  - direct rules referencing builtin chains are not changed. This time `INPUT` is used.

This peculiarity can be seen in the python code [`fw_direct.py`](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/blob/v1.3.2/src/firewall/core/fw_direct.py#L434):

> ```
>         # if nftables is in use, just put the direct rules in the chain
>         # specified by the user. i.e. don't append _direct.
>         if not self._fw.nftables_enabled \
>            and backend.is_chain_builtin(ipv, table, chain):
>             _chain = "%s_direct" % (chain)
> ```

In both cases anything created using `firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0` (followed by the same syntax as what would be provided to an `iptables` command without including the table and chain) will be seen by a packet before *firewalld* itself sees it.

For the prority value: this affects the order of the rules you want to use in case their order matters. If, by the way rules were chosen by the administrator, a rule doesn't depend on previous rules, then its priority doesn't matter and can even stay the same. To ensure a rule is added after other rules, increase its priority:

> If you want to make sure that a rule will be added after another one,
> use a low priority for the first and a higher for the following.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. BTW I'm using iptables because docker doesn't yet support nftables and I don't want to use a compatibility shim.